# Pandas - flatten columns

Tags: python, pandas

After:

1. aggregating with `sum()`
2. grouping by `['country', 'match_id']`
3. creating a mean column with `mean(axis=1)`

I ended up with this:

```
                     Gls  Ast  avg_attack 
                     sum  sum 
country    match_id
Argentina  20eb96e2  0.10 0.20 0.15
           18eb43e2  0.20 0.30 0.25
...
```

Now, how do I flatten my dataframe back to this?

```
country     match_id Gls  Ast  avg_attack 
Argentina  20eb96e2  0.10 0.20 0.15
Argentina  18eb43e2  0.20 0.30 0.25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`pandas.Index.get_level_values`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html?highlight=get_level_values#pandas.Index.get_level_values) to flatten the hierarchical index in columns then [**`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html?highlight=reset_index#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) to reset the multi index in rows.

```
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
out = df.reset_index()
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

     Country  match_id  Gls   Ast   avg_attack
0  Argentina  20eb96e2  0.10  0.20        0.15
1  Argentina  18eb43e2  0.20  0.30        0.25
```